# ReadInt32, BinaryReader, c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a binary byte array.
In C#, it's very easy to read it with BinaryReader and ReadInt32 (that's what I need). like this:

```
reader = new BinaryReader ( new MemoryStream( data ), new UnicodeEncoding() );

m_headerVersion = reader.ReadInt32();
m_width         = reader.ReadInt32();
m_height        = reader.ReadInt32();
...
```

How can I do the same thing in c++ (MFC)?
What should I include to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Ick, that looks more like Java or C# than C++. Are you sure you need to `new` all those objects?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you are using unmanaged C++, and you have to write it your self. C++ and C# different languages after all.

But you can do something similar using STL streams.

```
std::stringstream reader;
reader << data;
reader >> m_headerVersion;
reader >> m_width;
reader >> m_height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your data in a

```
char* data;
```

You can get it into an int32_t by casting it, i.e.:

```
int32_t m_headerVersion = int32_t(*data);
int32_t m_width  = int32_t(*(data + sizeof(int32_t)));
int32_t m_height  = int32_t(*(data + 2*sizeof(int32_t)));
```

That's the basic idea. You should be able to wrap this functionality in an easy-to-use stream-style interface.